# Hilarious Juvenile Science Fiction space adventure from 1950s or 1960s

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

This was a laugh out loud funny space adventure novel for young adults with interconnected stories about a rather bumbling but lucky young space adventurer, possibly a cadet...Its opening chapter, as I recall, took place on an interstellar garbage scow (like the later TV show Quark).  After being jettisoned with the trash our hero went on to a series of space adventures each one as rollicking as the last.  At one time, I though this was Starman Jones, but it's not.  I've been hunting for this book for 50 years with no luck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember any of the cover art?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: It's not [Tom Corbett Space Cadet?](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/8081), not so much bumbling as naive.

Comment: It might possibly be Bill The Galactic Hero, 1965, by Harry Harrison, though the synopsis is different from wha tyousay.  It might also be Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers, 1973, though again the synopsis is different.

Answer (score 7):

This is "[Lancelot Biggs, Spaceman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Remarkable_Exploits_of_Lancelot_Biggs,_Spaceman)" a 'fix-up' novel of short stories that originally appeared from 1939-43, by Nelson Bond.

[image]

Comment: Most if not all of the Lancelot Biggs yarns can be read (in a slightly different form as they were revised for the fix-up novel) at the Internet Archive. The first one is here: https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_Adventures_v01n04_1939-11_missing_ifc/page/n33/mode/1up